# Alamofire could not cast type of NSCFString to dictionary

Tags: json, xcode, swift4, alamofire

I'm trying to use Alamofire to get a response from web-service.
The service is returning a string in JSON format but I'm getting the error: 'Could not cast value of type NSCFString to NSDictionary'

My code is:

```
func getSoFromMo() {
        let apiUrl: String = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

        Alamofire.request(apiUrl)
            .responseJSON{ response in
                print(response)

                if let resultJSON = response.result.value {
                    let resultObj: Dictionary = resultJSON as! Dictionary<String, Any>  <==== Breaks on this line
                    self.soNum = resultObj["soNumber"] as! String
                    self.lblValidate.text = "\(self.soNum)"
                    } else {
                    self.soNum = "not found!"
                }
        }
```

When I print the response I get - SUCCESS: {"SoNumber": "SO-1234567"}

When I test the URL using Postman the result is: "{\"soNumber\": \"SO-1234567\"}" including all the quotes, so the format doesn't quite look correct to me, perhaps the leading and trailing double quotes are throwing it off?

Comment: The error states clearly that `value` is **not** a dictionary. But JSON in JSON is pretty unusual. Please replace  `print(response)` with `print(String(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8)!)` and add the result.

Comment: here is the resulting printout: "{\"soNumber\": \"SO-1234567\"}"

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear. The result is a JSON string rather than a deserialized dictionary.

You have to add a line to deserialize the string

```
func getSoFromMo() {
    let apiUrl: String = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

    Alamofire.request(apiUrl)
        .responseJSON { response in
            print(response)
            do {
                if let data = response.data, 
                   let resultObj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any] {
                      self.soNum = resultObj["soNumber"] as! String
                      self.lblValidate.text = self.soNum // no String Interpolation, soNum IS a string
                } else {
                    self.soNum = "not found!"
                }
            } catch {
               print(error)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I gave this a shot and now get a different error: "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allows fragments not set"  Sounds like I need to allow that option, how do I do that?

Comment: With the given output this error must not occur. Do you exactly use my code? For example `response.data’

Comment: So, I figured out the allow fragments option and no longer get that error, but now it drops into the 'else' block and says 'not found'

Comment: If the *printout* is exactly the value in your comment below the question my code must work even without options.

Comment: double checked and I am using your exact code, the data returned is "{\"soNumber\": \"SO-1234567\"}"

Comment: Huge thanks for your help thus far, I am no longer getting any errors but even though I am getting data back, the try JSONSerialization.jsonObject falls into 'not found' block . Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, the error in not comprehensible if `data` is `"{\"soNumber\": \"SO-1234567\"}"` which is definitely a JSON string representing a dictionary.